# Centering <DIV> with CSS

Tags: html, css, center

I have built the following website:

http://passive.expert/

I am trying to center the "Gold Plan" white CSS box so that it neatly fits underneath the "Our Package" heading.

The CSS code that needs editing for the white box is:

```
.investment_plans{

    height: 100%;
    background-position: center 0;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom:120px;
}
```

I have been playing around with this for hours and am unable to find a way to center the box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: In this case, add ``margin: 0 auto`` to the white block div and it will be centered.

Comment: Centering a `div`: `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`, shouldn't have a `position` and should't have child elements that make the element use 100% width - for starters.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center a div using CSS you can try the code below it centers div in the middle of the screen

```
.investment_plans{
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center 0;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom:120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```